# How to restrict zoom in/out in Google Map to a given specified value?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have included a map into my PHP website. These are the details I have centered the map at this position (9.0609902,76.5341999).

I have set the zoom level to 6. I am not much acquainted to the JavaScript. I don't want to zoom-in to the map. I want to restrict the zoom level to maximum value of 6 & don't want to allow users to zoom more. That is, I don't want the value of zoom parameter to be more than 6. And the maximum zoom out level should be 2.

My map code:

```
<script>
    function initialize()
    {
        var laa=9.0609902;
        var lon=76.5341999;
        var myLatlng=new google.maps.LatLng(laa,lon);
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(laa,lon),
            zoom:6,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        var image = 'mapmarkers/you-are-here-2.png';

        var opt = { minZoom: 6, maxZoom: 9 };
        mapProp.setOptions(opt);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'I am Here.',
            icon: image
        });
    }

    function loadScript()
    {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
    window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
```

This doesn't work in my map. Why?

```
var opt = { minZoom: 6, maxZoom: 9 };
mapProp.setOptions(opt);
```

Comment: mapProp is just a hash object with properties. You can't use setter methods on that. You either feed the original map with a hash that has the minZoom and maxZoom, or do ```map.setOptions(opt);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then try this:

```
<script>
    //map included.
    function initialize()
    {
        var myLatlng=new google.maps.LatLng(laa,lonn);
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(laa,lonn),
            zoom:6,
            maxZoom: 6,
            minZoom:2,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        var image = 'mapmarkers/you-are-here-2.png';

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'I am Here.',
            icon: image
        });
    }

    function loadScript()
    {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
    window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
//map included.
function initialize()
{
    var myLatlng=new google.maps.LatLng(laa,lonn);
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(laa,lonn),
        zoom:6,
        maxZoom: 6,
        minZoom:2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    var image = 'mapmarkers/you-are-here-2.png';

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'I am Here.',
        icon: image
    });
}

function loadScript()
{
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
window.onload = loadScript;
```

Comment: Can you explain what is different? Why does this work?